# quickbooks desktop sdk retrieve line item detail

Tags: quickbooks

I want to retrieve QuickBooks detail record. For example, estimatelinedetail, estimatelinegroupdetail,journalentryline, salesorderlinedetail
,salesorderlinegroupdetail etc.

Comment: What does your code look like? What did you try so far? What programming language? Can you give us ANY detail AT ALL?

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the tag `<IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>` so as to return the line items in a transaction.

thanks,

Rajesh Iyer